# Not a footprint to be seen

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

...a kingdom of isolation - jk.

A small young chap went on a journey with some friends and was inspired to write this poem about one of his traveling companions. Who's the poem about?

> Precedes the procession of lady and lord
>   Last in secession an enraged orc horde
>   Carefully navigating to second then fifth
>   Looking through roads for most targets to hit
>   Leading the lost but not the confused
>   Humor unwelcome, granted a wee bit amused?
>   First and foremost to be titled "skilled"
>   But just 1 point for an elephant killed

Hint:

> This puzzle involves wordplay. The context of the lines of the poem verify the answer, but each line (expect for the last one) is used to get the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on the [answer by @Flawedspirit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/51563/26596)

Going line by line:

Precedes the procession of lady and lord

> L - first letter of lady and lord

Last in secession an enraged orc horde

> E - last letter of the entire line

Carefully navigating to second then fifth

> G - fifth letter of second word

Looking through roads for most targets to hit

> O - the most common letter in the line

Leading the lost but not the confused

> L - first letter in "lost" but not "confused"

Humor unwelcome, granted a wee bit amused?

> A - unsure

First and foremost to be titled "skilled"

> S - first letter in "skilled"

All of the above lines, both in wordplay and in contextual meaning, plus the last line, lead you to

> LEGOLAS

Comment: nice! a is "a little bit" of "amused"

Comment: As feedback, there is no way at all I would have gotten the line-by-line bit if it hadn't already been solved by @Flawedspirit, and therefore known what letter I was looking for.

Answer (score 11):

**What I think is the answer:**

> Legolas is who this poem is about.

I arrived at it by making sense of some of the lines, which I'll try to articulate.

A small young chap

> Frodo Baggins.

Precedes the procession of lady and lord

> He is of great help in getting Aragorn crowned King Elessar of Gondor and marrying Arwen.

Looking through roads for most targets to hit

> Is able to spot targets to shoot at easily across great distance and in the middle of battle.

Leading the lost but not the confused

> After the Fellowship split, Aragorn, Legolas, Gimli, and the other two hobbits are in a sense "lost" to Frodo and Sam, but they still have their own mission and goal which they have some clue how to accomplish.

Humor unwelcome, granted a wee bit amused?

> Legolas never seems to laugh at anything, but he does show slight amusement at funny situations.

First and foremost to be titled "skilled"

> Fairly self-explanatory. He's is immensely skilled with his bow and the other weapons he carries, along with his grace and dexterity.

But just 1 point for an elephant killed

> Takes down an entire war elephant, along with the small structure on its back, and all the Haradrim on it, leading Gimli to declare that the elephant still only counts as one point in their friendly killing rivalry.

Comment: +1 for the correct answer and explaining some of the contextual clues correctly (intended to affirm the answer), but each line is used to specifically lead you to the answer (except for the last one which you got correct). In other words, you got the correct answer, but haven't solved the puzzle, so I cannot accept this answer as is